# Automatically schedule a page on publish

Tags: workflow, event-receivers, publishing, schedule

When the user publishes a page, I need to automatically schedule it with a start date being as soon as possible, and the end date being a year from the start date. I've tried the event receiver approach (i.e. creating a ScheduledItem and setting the dates accordingly then ListItem.Update() and ScheduledItem.Schedule()) but I get an errro to do with workflow's that I just can't seem to get around.

Does anybody know *any* other way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it look like this:

```
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://serverName:1111/"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
            {
                SPList list=web.Lists["Doc Library"];
                SPListItem listItem = list.GetItemById(1);              
                ScheduledItem scheduledItem = null;
                if (ScheduledItem.IsScheduledItem(listItem))
                {
                    scheduledItem = ScheduledItem.GetScheduledItem(listItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new System.ArgumentException
                      ("SPListItem must support scheduling",
                      "listItem");
                }

                DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2011, 4, 6, 22, 50, 00);
                DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2011, 4, 6, 22, 51, 00);
                scheduledItem.StartDate = startDate;
                scheduledItem.EndDate = endDate;
                scheduledItem.ListItem.Update();
                scheduledItem.Schedule();
            }
        }
```

Source from my bookmarks: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/programmatically-schedule-an-item-in-sharepoint-2010/

Perhaps if the link doesn't help can you provide more information, perhaps your code isn't quite right on the event receiver. Can you also post the error because afaik you are heading down the right path.

Comment: It does indeed, it looks exactly like that. What event would you advise this code be included in? I've tried "CheckingIn" and I get an error with a correlation ID (doesn't even get as far as scheduling it), and on "Updating" it appears to have all worked but when I check the page Status I see the error (next to Page Approval failed): "The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the items require a different type of information." Thanks a lot Hugh.

Comment: I am thinking ItemCheckedIn would be the best place also check properties.ListItem.File.Level == SPFileLevel.Published

Comment: Thanks a lot Hugh, I'll give moving it to CheckedIn a go and report back, appreciate your reply mate thanks.

Comment: It never satisfies "properties.ListItem.File.Level == SPFileLevel.Published" on CheckedIn I'm afraid Hugh. Not sure where to go from here!?

Comment: The events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.project.server.events_di_pj14mref.aspx An example of checking if a page is published http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797526/how-to-determine-if-a-publishing-page-in-sharepoint-2007-is-actually-published

Comment: Completely removing the If clause (so that it definitely runs - I tested when only clicking the publish button so I was sure the code was 'relevant' during debugging anyway) now asks me to make sure the file is checked out first. So I programmatically checked the file out, and now it's giving me further problems and errors regarding workflows. One last question - could it just be that this is too tricky to achieve from an event receiver due to the nature of them running asynchronously with other workflows that may have been started? Should I not look to alternative ways of achieving this?

Comment: [In theory] You could have a timer job do it for published pages that don't have the the end date set. Either a one off timer job delayed in the event receiver or a reoccurring one. But in reality I just cannot see why this doesn't work, there has been plenty of times I have set properties in this way.

Comment: I can't myself. I've tried everything I know of and now it's just gettin ridiculous programmatically checking out the file etc. I've even tried playing about with putting it before/after calling the base event handler.

Comment: This is turning into a discussion, so all I will say is for the timer job you want to query GetPublishingPages for the pages with the correct status and enddate. If this is beyond then maybe someone else can shed some light on this strange behavior.